# StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up Command duration or timeout

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

[image: AT line 106]i got this exception.please resolve it.org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Command duration or timeout: 5.10 seconds

CODE:

```
 List<WebElement> select_year = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span"));
    for(WebElement ele: select_year)
    {

        String fyear=ele.getText();
        if((syear).equals(fyear))
        {
            System.out.println(syear);
            System.out.println(fyear);
            ele.click();
            List<WebElement>select_month=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span"));
            for(WebElement ele2:select_month)
            {
                String fmonth=ele2.getText();
                if((smonth).equals(fmonth))
                {
                    ele2.click();
                    List<WebElement>select_day=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span"));
                    for(WebElement ele3:select_day)
                    {
                        String fday=ele3.getText();
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        if((sday).equals(fday))
                        {
                            ele3.click();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share HTML as well.. for better solution or use `break` statement inside loop after click on element when if condition become true.. problem solved

Comment: which HTML you want @SaurabhGaur

Comment: Why are you doing this is loop??

Comment: To click on year try in one line as `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span[text() = " + syear+"]")).click();` and same as for other and avoid looping.

Comment: i going to select Year,Month and Day respectively. but this error exist.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur thats one line only on eclipse.it shows here like multi

Comment: What do you mean shows here like multi ?? I didn't understand..try provided answer and let me know..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122150/discussion-between-boopathi-and-saurabh-gaur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to looping here. You need to find just Single element with text and select as below :-

```
//To select year
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-pop‌​up dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span[text() = " + syear+"]")).click();

 //To select month
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-pop‌​up dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span[text() = " + smonth+"]")).click();

//To select day
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-pop‌​up dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span[text() = " + sday+"]")).click();
```

**Edited** :-  If you want loop here, you just need to `break` the loop when `if` condition becomes true as below :-

```
//To select year
List<WebElement> select_year = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span"));
 for(WebElement ele: select_year)
{
    String fyear=ele.getText();
    if((syear).equals(fyear))
    {
        ele.click();
        break;
    }
 }

//To select month 
List<WebElement> select_month = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span"));
 for(WebElement ele: select_year)
{
    String fmonth = ele.getText();
    if((smonth).equals(fmonth))
    {
        ele.click();
        break;
    }
 }

//To select day
List<WebElement> select_day = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='uib-datepicker-popup dropdown-menu ng-scope']/li/div/table/tbody/tr/td/button/span"));
 for(WebElement ele: select_year)
{
    String fday = ele.getText();
    if((sday).equals(fday))
    {
        ele.click();
        break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: its all conditions.we need to loooping here :(

Comment: Ok then use proper break statement and doing each loop in separate.try edited answer and let me know..

Comment: where is use break.Please tell me

Comment: Got @Saurabh Gaur